# How add category programmatically magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, category, programmatically

How to create categories programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to create category programmatically:

```
$parentId = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;

$parentCategory = $this->_objectManager
                      ->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
                      ->load($parentId);
$category = $this->_objectManager
                ->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');

$cate = $category->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name','test') // replace "test" with your category name.
            ->getFirstItem();

if(!isset($cate->getId())) {
    $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath())
        ->setParentId($parentId)
        ->setName('test') //replace "test" with your category name.
        ->setIsActive(true);
    $category->save();
}
```

Comment: I have tried above but it is not work.

Comment: My code is working fine with attributes, description, price etc but it not importing category. I think the issue with below function.


$category->save();

Comment: @user2710761 Ok let me check it again.

Comment: @user2710761 I have updated the code please try it, hope it helps you!

Comment: @user2710761 please don't forget to upvote.

Comment: I found other solution. Thank you for your quick help my friend.